# unhandeled exception org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, json

I'm using Retrofit library to make httpClient post request but,
I can't pass response body to JSONObject constructor,
when I try to pass response to JSONObject  using :

```
org.json.JSONObject Jobject = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonData);
```

I got the following exception :

> unhandeled exception org.json.JSONObject

**My Code:**

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    String jsonData = response.body().toString();

                    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                display_message.setText(t.toString());
            }
        });
```

The expected returned value from the following statement:

```
String jsonData = response.body().source().toString();
```

Is :
`{"is_new_user":true,"messing_user_data["mobile_number","country_code","password","pin"]}`

But the  exact returned result is :

```
[size=90 text={"is_new_user":true,"messing_user_data":["mobile_number","countr…]
```

Any Ideas help me.

Comment: Add `JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);` inside a `try` block and catch `JSONException` in the `catch` block.

Comment: Can you write log jsonData? Please check is it format json file? JsonObject or JsonArray?

Comment: Please see above additional updates

Answer (score 0):

You should surround your

```
JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
```

with a try-catch block

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){

            String jsonData = response.body().toString();

            try {
                JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        display_message.setText(t.toString());
    }
});
```

And try to check your json string if it has the correct format as you need

Comment: After surrounded JSONObject with try-catch I had the follwing exception :
org.json.JSONException: Value okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@248a0209 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Well, it's obvious, since your string is not a valid JSON Object. Please check again your string {"is_new_user":true,"messing_user_data["mobile_number","country_code","password","pin"]}